# Using PyUNO on Windows and CentOS

Tags: python, openoffice.org, pyuno

Is there any way to use OpenOffice's [PyUNO](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/PyUNO_bridge) without using the version of Python that comes with OpenOffice?

I mean, can I install a package (on Windows and CentOS) that uses the version of Python that's already on the server?

I'm trying to use OpenOffice in headless mode so that I can do document conversion with a script (ultimately on a hosted server running CentOS) but my development work is being done on Windows and, occasionally, the Mac).  I'm having nothing but trouble getting this to work.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994429/developing-with-pyuno-for-windowsis-python-2-6-supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use PyUNO with just any version of Python. You need to use the specific one that's integrated into your OpenOffice installation. However, the very latest OO (3.1 I believe) comes (on all platforms) with the very latest Python (2.6.2 I believe), so if you can upgrade your OpenOffice to the very latest released version on all platforms, you should be just fine.

Comment: This isn't true on Linux--at least, on Ubuntu (Debian). In Ubuntu, pyUNO is a package that integrates into the system's standard Python installation. Hence my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/994429/developing-with-pyuno-for-windowsis-python-2-6-supported