# Python 2.7 with pyuno

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x, pyuno

I am having python 2.7 installed on my windows 7. I have installed Libre Office 3.4 which comes with python 2.6. Hence i am not able to import uno and unohelper even after setting all environment variables.

I need python 2.7 thus cannot revert back to python 2.6, as i earlier had python 2.6 working with open office 3. I recently changed to LibreOffice 3.4 and Python 2.7(ActivePython 2.7).

Is there any way i can make python 2.7 to import uno and unohelper of LibreOffice 3.4

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.pyc` files and C extensions are not compatible between 2.6 and 2.7 Python versions. Install [pylauncher](https://bitbucket.org/vinay.sajip/pylauncher/downloads) and use python2.6 shebang in scripts that work with Libre Office.

From the link provided in the answer to [OpenOffice.org development with pyUno for Windows—which Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994429/openoffice-org-development-with-pyuno-for-windowswhich-python) question:

> Terms: Let's call the version of Python installed with OpenOffice the
>   'OO-Python'. Let's call the version of Python installed separately (to
>   c:\Python26, for example) the 'System-Python'.
>
> You need to know SIX things to sucessfully import the uno module into
>   your System-Python interpreter. 1) The OO-Python version number. **Your
>   System-Python version number must be the same as your OO-Python
>   version number.** [emphasis mine]
>   ...

Comment: I do not have Python2.6 installed on my system so i tried giving the path of python.exe present in the LibreOffice 3.4 as "C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 3.4\program\python.exe". I am unaware as to what i am trying is correct or not and whether this way of providing python executable version required for my script is correct or not.

Comment: @PyBegginer: If the versions of System and LibreOffice python are different then you can't run the code that uses `pyuno` installed with LibreOffice with your System python. It doesn't prevent you from running it using the python from the path you posted. `pylauncher` allows you to run your scripts without specifying python version every time (you do it once inside your script in the `'#!'`-line). View [the screencast](http://www.red-dove.com/screencasts/launcher/launcher.html).

Answer (score 3):

ubuntu 13.10 and later , you need to install openoffice 4.1.1.

1. uninstall libreoffice and openoffice

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove libreoffice* openoffice*
   sudo apt-get autoremove
   ```
2. install Apache OpenOffice 4.1.1 on 64 bit Ubuntu

   ```
   wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86-64_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   cd en-GB/DEBS
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   cd desktop-integration
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
3. install Apache OpenOffice 4.1.1 on 32 bit Ubuntu

   ```
   wget sourceforge.net/projects/openofficeorg.mirror/files/4.1.1/binaries/en-GB/Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   tar -xzvf Apache_OpenOffice_4.1.1_Linux_x86_install-deb_en-GB.tar.gz
   cd en-GB/DEBS
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   cd desktop-integration
   sudo dpkg -i *.deb
   ```
4. touch uno.pth for python2.7

   ```
   echo /opt/openoffice4/program |sudo tee /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/uno.pth
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**In ubuntu 14.04**

open the terminal and run the following command...

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice python-genshi python-cairo python-lxml python-setuptools
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-script-provider-python
easy_install uno
```